# Irreducible polynomial which becomes reducible under linear constraints

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Given an irreducible polynomial over the reals $p({\bf x})$, is there a technique which allows one to determine whether there exist linear constraints $l_1({\bf x})=l_2({\bf x})=l_k({\bf x})=0$ such that once imposed $p$ factorizes into irreducible polynomial factors of predetermined degree? To make an example let 
$$
p(a,b,c,d,e)=2 \sqrt{2} -3 \sqrt{2}  b^2-3 \sqrt{2}  c^2-3 \sqrt{2}  d^2-3 \sqrt{2}  e^2-3 \sqrt{2}  a^2+6 b^2 d+6 \sqrt{3} b c e-3 c^2 d+3 \sqrt{3} c^2 a-2 d^3-3 d e^2+6 d a^2-3 \sqrt{3} e^2 a
$$
it is clear that if we impose the constraint $l_1=e$, $l_2=b$, $l_3=c$ then $$p=1/3 (\sqrt{2} - 2 d) (\sqrt{6} - 3 a + \sqrt{3} d) (\sqrt{6} + 3 a + \sqrt{3} d)$$
that is the polynomial can be factorized into factors of degree 1. However, there is a choice of $l_1, l_2, l_3$ such that the polynomial factorizes into two irreducible factors of degree 1 and 2? I know nothing of algebraic geometry but my intuitive understanding is that the constraints imply that one is working in a quotient space, and that the factorization problem takes place there. I would be glad if you could point me to the relevant concepts or literature.

Comment: This is an intresting problem! As for a phrasing of the problem in algebraic geometry, the question can be phrased as if a hypersurface $X$, when restricted to a codimension $3$ subplane, is the union of hypersurfaces of the desired degrees.